# reset password in android studio with firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, reset-password

I need to add a password reset part to my application but in my application user's email and password store in the realtime database not in the authentication database. Like this:

[image]

Actually I do not care about security so I just built this for my education purpose. Can you give me any tutorial or example that I can follow to code the reset password part?

Answer (score 1):

Should be relatively simple to do.
Video here on it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-DRdI_xpvQ

However, please do not store passwords as raw text data. It is insecure and not good practice. Sure its fine for demo applications but you should store them using some kind of encoding/encryption/hashing.

Comment: That tutorial for the authentication database. Is it working for me?

Comment: I recommend using authentication if you want a user to login. Also have a login activity as opposed to storing the data inside of a firebase database. It is built into firebase as authentication. Go to Tools firebase authentication it will take you through the steps. Then you will not need to store the data inside of the database. Authentification is basically a sign in method which is safe and protected. Its also simple to implement and should be fine for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Firebase authenticator has a function to reset the password via email, if you want to try with that one.

If you want to stay just with realtime DB my suggestion is to update that value for that specific user [Google Firebase Documentation for that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update)